# How to create a DLL project for Qt 5 in visual studio Qt add on

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt5

I want to create a Qt DLL project in Viusal studio , My Qt version is 5 and in visual studio 2010 , Can any body show me how to do it???
Thanks a lot .

Comment: yes i can see that , but i want to create dll project not exe project , thanks any way.

Comment: If you select `Qt5 Projects`, do you see `Qt Library` ? (I'm asking, because I have Qt4 on my system and don't know if it's the same for Qt5)

Comment: i try that , but that just create a static lib not dll.

Comment: for Qt4, you get a wizard where you can check/uncheck "Create Static Library (.lib)"

Comment: yes it has a check box .but when i go to the directory , there is only a lib file , i want a dll file not a lib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Qt5 comes with the same templates, but anyway, this is how I would do it for Qt4:
[image]

[image]

If you can't disable the `Create Static Library` for the Qt5 library template, then you can change the `Configuration Type` of the library project afterwards (right-click your project in Solution Explorer > Properties):

[image]